# Shell - How to rename files in the midle of file name?

Tags: bash, batch-rename, wildcards

I have to resize images, and want to rename them on the fly
Names are like following

- Compet-210-123456.jpg
- Compet-210-123457.jpg
- ...
- Compet-211-123555.jpg
  and

I would like to inject **4k** between two numbers like

- Compet-211-**4k**-123555.jpg

currently I know only to add **4k** at the ***end*** like following:

```
for img in ./Compet-[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].jpg do; 
  convert "$img" -resize "3840x2160^" \
                 -gravity center \
                 -crop 3840x2160 \
                 "${img%.jpg}-4k.jpg"
done
```

Comment: [Bash pitfall number one](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).

Comment: Thanks @KamilMaciorowski for heads up.  I've updated loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the original filename, sometimes it's possible to precisely trim the unneeded half:

```
head=${img%-*.jpg}
tail=${img#./Compet-*-}
newimg=$head-4k-$tail
```

The other method is to apply a regex match using `=~`:

```
re='^\./(Compet-[0-9]+)-([0-9]+\.jpg)$'
if [[ $img =~ $re ]]; then
    newimg=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}-4k-${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
    convert "$img" ... "$newimg"
fi
```

Bash uses the "POSIX Extended Regular Expression" regex syntax, and capture groups are placed in the BASH_REMATCH array.

I used a variable to hold the regex pattern because the quoting/escaping rules for right-hand side of `[[ ]]` can get a bit ugly otherwise.

Comment: thanks @user1686 .   Does "tail=${img#./Compet-*-}"   do not match Compet-123-4k-123456.jpg? thus only Compet-123-123456.jpg

Comment: If you use a single `#` or `%`, the asterisk will match as little as possible, 
so `-*-` will only match `-123-`. (But if you use double `##` or `%%` _then_ it will match as much as possible.)